# Blubird never hits the .catch statement

Tags: node.js, redis, bluebird

I am using Node.js, Bluebird and Redis.  Given:

```
redisClient.hmsetAsync([key, 'sn', sn, 'make', make])
    .then(redisClient.setAsync(key + ":radio", radioArray))
    .then(TMatic.send(res, 200))
    .catch(function (e) {
        console.log("Error reading file", e);
        TMatic.send(res, 500);
    });
```

When the "radioArray" is empty, redis throws this exception:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: ERR wrong number of arguments for command
```

This code always sends a 200 response back.  Whey doesn't it hit the .catch() method and throw a 500?

ANSWER!
After hacking for about a half hour, I came up with this. Thanks macareno.marco!

```
redisClient.hmsetAsync([key, 'sn', sn, 'make', make])
        .then(function saveRadios() {
            if (radioArray.length) {
                console.log("radio");
                return redisClient.setAsync(key + ":radio", radioArray)
            }
        })
        .then(function () {
            TMatic.send(res, 200);
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            console.log("Error:", e);
            TMatic.fail(e, res);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the line:
`.then(TMatic.send(res, 200))`
The parameter is being evaluated, and waiting for a function to be returned so bluebird may call it. You should use a function instead, like so:

```js
.then(function(res) {
    TMatic.send(res, 200);
}
```

Comment: Bingo.  After working a bit you have straightened me out!  I need to use functions essentially at each step so they don't get executed right away!  So above, both .then() statements need to be in functions.  When I did that, it worked.  Thanks!

Comment: @markthegrea Yes you got it way better than I explained myself, glad I could help.